# Alfresco tomcat service does not communicate with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, alfresco, windows-server-2012-r2

I am currently upgrading a Windows 2003 Server to a 2012R2. 
I had to merge several components including :

-Joomla

-VtigerCRM

-Alfresco

The two first components did just fine (or almost but that's not the point). However, I am having a hard time configuring Alfresco.

Alfresco runs two Windows services : alfrescoTomcat and alfrescoOpenoffice

My server returns a 500 HTTP Error when booting up those services. Which is explained by the following tomcat logs :

```
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:50 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8188
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:51 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8553
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2648 ms
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:51 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor alfresco.xml
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:53 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Jul 17, 2017 8:14:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
08:15:04,109  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/repository.properties]
08:15:04,117  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/domain/transaction.properties]
08:15:04,120  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean] Loading properties file from file [C:\ProgramFiles\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\module\org_alfresco_module_dod5015\alfresco-global.properties]
08:15:04,121  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertiesFactoryBean] Loading properties file from file [C:\ProgramFiles\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\module\org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart\alfresco-global.properties]
08:15:04,198  INFO  [alfresco.config.JndiPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from class path resource [alfresco/alfresco-shared.properties]
08:15:08,987  WARN  [hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] Could not obtain connection metadata
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'alfresco'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:855)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:774)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'alfresco'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2928)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:771)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3649)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1176)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2558)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1485)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
    ... 77 more
```

And it goes on and on for hundreds of lines. This is the very first error.

My main concern is about this :

```
 08:15:08,987  WARN  [hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory] Could not obtain connection metadata
    org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
    PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'alfresco'@'localhost' 
    (using password: YES))
```

I checked the alfresco-global.properties file, which specifies the correct port, database name and credentials.

The database can be accessed with these credentials manualy via Command Prompt, the base and tables exists, 'alfresco'@'localhost' has every privileges on alfresco.* .

Here is a TCPView : 
[image: TCPView]

My lead is that tomcat can not communicate with MySQL, but I might be wrong. 
Does anyone has any idea on what may be happening ? What am I missing ?
I tried a pretty fair amount of solutions found on the Internet, none of them worked so far. That's why I come to you.

Thanks for your time, I'll post further information as I discover them or after your requests.

Kind regards,

Comment: How did you install the tomcat instance? It looks like the tomcat\shared path is not used since there is no log output for the mysql driver. s. http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/configfiles-change-path.html

Comment: Please ensure that the alfresco user has the required privileges to create and modify tables. Provide if not present and try restarting.

Comment: @HeikoRobert The tomcat instance was installed using the provided installer. Then I replaced some directories such as alf_data by the 2003 versions. Each alfresco (2003 and 2012) are using the same version

Comment: @Sheljithkrishnan GRANT USAGE on *.* TO 'alfresco'@'localhost' identified by password ''
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'alfresco'.* to 'alfresco'@'localhost'

Comment: @Xcrowzz Am not that good in mysql quries. Can you please try the below queries, i got it from alfresco docs...
grant all on alfresco.* to 'alfresco'@'localhost' identified by 'password ' with grant option;
grant all on alfresco.* to 'alfresco'@'localhost.localdomain' identified by 'password ' with grant option;

Comment: @HeikoRobert turns out you were right, the file was not used because of a mistake from Alfresco's developers. The path declaring it in the catalina.properties file was wrong. I corrected it and everything went as expected.